# Occupancy Grid Coordinates

Tags: ros, navigation, coordinate-system, costmap, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

This might be a newbie question but i need a help with it or at least to be pointed in the right direction. I need to extract/acquire the (x, y) coordinates of a given map's (grid) cells to be used in a path planning program.

- like in the RVIZ that you click somewhere on the map and it prints out the coordinates of that specific location. what i need to achieve is to acquire all of available "unoccupied" cells coordinates of a given map for my Node to calculate a STC path for the robot to travel.

How can i achieve this goal through a ROS node?

Does the (x, y) map coordinates system follow a certain rule? for example (0, 0) is always at a specific corner or there is a system for row and column numbering, etc.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207914/occupancy-grid-coordinates/) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-04-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Please have a look into [yaml](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#YAML_format) of map you are using.

using `origin` and `resolution`  you can find position of each cell.

---

> **origin** : The 2-D pose of the
> lower-left pixel in the map, as (x, y,
> yaw), with yaw as counterclockwise
> rotation (yaw=0 means no rotation).
> Many parts of the system currently
> ignore yaw.

---

> **resolution** : Resolution of the map, meters / pixel

---

**Edit**

[Occupancy Grid msg](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) member `data` is having

> Occupancy probabilities are in the
> range [0,100].  Unknown is -1.

Use `free_thresh` param to get Unoccupied cells (i.e free cells).

> **free_thresh** : Pixels with occupancy
> probability less than this threshold
> are considered completely free.

if `free_thresh: 0.196` then all cells with occupancy lessthan 19.6 (and not -1 ) are free .

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-04-26**:
Thanks so much! This answers the second part of my question. a little twist though, what if its not a static map (would local_costmap_params.yaml serve the same purpose?) **Any idea about the first part of the problem (extracting unoccupied grid coordinates) through use of cpp codes?**

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2015-04-26**:
check update, yes if map is not static you have to use cost map but you need good localization.